# XCode 7.3.1 - symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, linker-errors, sharekit

I am trying to integrate [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/install/) to my iOS project. I've added a few additional frameworks (Such as SystemConfiguration.framework) into the project, but I always run into the same error while linking:

```
  "_SecItemUpdate", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_kSecAttrLabel", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_SecItemDelete", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_SecItemAdd", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_kSecAttrService", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:


      objc-class-ref in SHK.o


      ltmp1 in SHKMail.o


      objc-class-ref in SHKMail.o


      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MFMailComposeViewController_$_SHK in SHKMail.o


  "_kSecClassGenericPassword", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_kSecReturnData", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_kSecClass", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:andPassword:forServiceName:updateExisting:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_SecItemCopyMatching", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:


      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o


  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:


      -[Reachability connectionRequired] in Reachability.o


      -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] in Reachability.o


  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:


      +[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in Reachability.o


  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:


      +[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in Reachability.o


  "_kSecReturnAttributes", referenced from:


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


      +[SFHFKeychainUtils deleteItemForUsername:andServiceName:error:] in SFHFKeychainUtils.o


  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:


      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o


  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:


      -[Reachability stopNotifier] in Reachability.o


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64


clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obfys.png) is a snapshot of how I added all additional frameworks. What might be wrong with my project settings? Any advices would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem. I think the developers in WeChat are lousy. They never make their sample work.

To fix the issue,you need to add Security.framework to your project.